# C# Socket SocketAsyncEventArgs reuse socket - ERRAddrAlreadyInUse

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to write a high performance lib for Sockets with a lot of preallocating. I am using SocketAsyncEventArgs XXXAsync methods. When I try to re-use the socket for 2nd time after calling

> _socket.DisconnectAsync(_socketAsyncEventArgs)

and setting

> _socketAsyncEventArgs.DisconnectReuseSocket = true;

Before I make the disconnect call, i get ERRAddrAlreadyInUse on 2nd connect call. I have tried the following options when I create the Socket object, however nothing changes. I am aware I could call Close and create new Socket, but that would allocate new object every time I call my main function, which is bad.

```
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, new LingerOption(false, 0));
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
```

I have also tried to set ReuseAddress to true, but nothing changed
I'm waiting for the first disconnect to finish and then afterwards I call the method which initiates the connection again. I am also not 100% sure if I should be using different SocketAsyncEventArgs for Connect/Disconnect call, since this is a socket client I see no problems with using 1.

```
private void SocketConnect()
{
    try
    {
        if(!_init)
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
            {
                UseOnlyOverlappedIO = true,
                ReceiveBufferSize = _receiveBuffer.Length,
                SendBufferSize = _sendBuffer.Length,
            };
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, new LingerOption(false, 0));
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);

            _socketAsyncEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            _socketAsyncEventArgs.Completed += _socketProc;

            _init = !_init;
         }
         _socketAsyncEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = _proxy != null ?
         new IPEndPoint(_proxy.IP, _proxy.Port) : new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostAddresses(DestinationUri.Host)[0].MapToIPv4(), DestinationUri.Scheme == "https" ? 443 : 80);
         var res = _socket.ConnectAsync(_socketAsyncEventArgs);
         if(!res)
             _socketProc(_socket, _socketAsyncEventArgs);
     }
     catch(SocketException socketException)
     {
         _completedTask.SetResult(false);
         Debug.WriteLine($"SocketConnect: {socketException.Message} : {socketException.ErrorCode} : {socketException.SocketErrorCode}");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a TCP setting in registry for TIME_WAIT which is set to 120 by standard. Sad that only C Winsock documentation specifies this and not C# one. Guess I have to force close the socket and recreate.